# Warning dismissViewController error on iOS 7 but not iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have multiple storyboards in my current project. I have searched everywhere for a solution to this problem.

When the user is done editing information and chooses to save:

```
self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
```

iOS8: saves the information, dismisses the navigation controller connected to this edit view, and exits the storyboard to the previous storyboard of the stack.

iOS7: saves the information, does NOT dismiss the controller. Remains at same view and gives the following error: "Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!"

I need iOS7 to work the same as iOS8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

> navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)